# Boost documentation declaration

Tags: c++, boost, hyperlink, include

When using the boost online documentation. For example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/doc/html/boost/mutex.html

I cannot find the declaration section which should specify: Which file do I need to include to use a specific class? And which libraries do I need to link?

While I can derive this information from random code snippets on the internet, Is there some central place (like MSDN) that I can query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *very* old documentation.
Take a look at the [recent version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types):

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>

class mutex:
    boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    mutex();
    ~mutex();

    void lock();
    bool try_lock();
    void unlock();

    typedef platform-specific-type native_handle_type;
    native_handle_type native_handle();

    typedef unique_lock<mutex> scoped_lock;
    typedef unspecified-type scoped_try_lock;
};
```

See also **[Using and building the library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/build.html)** section.

Comment: Thanks, I see they included it in the new version (1.53)

Comment: @eshalev Not in 1.53, it already exists quite a long time. Note that 1.34 is 6 years old!